# Exam class: Remove line breaks for \titledquestion?

Tags: exam

I would like to (a) remove the line break between the colon and the start of the question and (b) remove the line break between the end of the question and the start of the solution as in the below image. Is this possible in the `exam` class?

[image]

Here is the tex source for the image above:

```
\documentclass[answers, 10pt]{exam}
\qformat{\mbox{\textbf{Question \thequestion~(}\thequestiontitle \textbf{):}}\enspace}
\unframedsolutions
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \titledquestion{Exercise Title}
  Show that $2 + 2 = 4$.
  \begin{solution}
    The answer is obvious.
  \end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```